# Reply-To header not picking the php variable

Tags: email, header, php

I am creating a page that sends the response from contact form within mail but `reply-to` is not working (the variable i am using is having value, but is not added within headers)

here's my code:

```
<?php

//$uname=$_REQUEST['uname'];
if(isset($_REQUEST['name']))
{
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['email']))
{
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
}   

if(isset($_REQUEST['phone']))
{
    $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['message']))
{
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
}

// TESTING IF VARIABLES HAVE VALUES
echo "$name $email $phone $message";
// RESULT: TRUE TILL HERE


if($name=="" || $email=="" || $phone=="" || $message=="")
{
    header("location:../?inst=invalid");    
}
else
{

    // ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------

// send e-mail to ...
$to="mail@example.com";

// Your subject
$subject="$name Contacted you via Contact Form";

// From
$headers  = "From: ME <no-reply@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To:' . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: info@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

print $message;
// send email
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
//$sentmail = mail($to1,$subject,$message,$header);
}

// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){
echo "Mail Sent.";
}
else {
    header("location:../landing/?status=verification-pending");
    }

?>
```

Now when i checked headers in my gmail, the value for $email doesn't appear in header information, Also no message is received. All I get is a blank message or may be $message is not printing anything like the same case i am facing with reply-to.

please help me a little with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but you can avoid having all those `if isset` by simply using `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and naming your submit button to "submit" and put your variables underneath that.

Comment: I think you cannot set anything to the header after you started to write something to the output. And your `echo` does write output. So put the header setting before that.

Comment: Oh Nice great idea @Fred-ii- I'll use it

Comment: Your Reply-To line is missing a space between the colon and the start of the email address.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Plus, it might even partially fix your problem. You could even use this snippet to get all your POST values => `foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) { $message.=$key.": " . $value . "\n"; }`

Comment: @FrankPl I just used echo to figure out if variable are retaining values or not. Its not working either, even after removing echo

Comment: @andrewsi Tried it buddy.. but no luck with that

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Put this at the top or bottom of your handler `var_dump($_POST);` see what results you get.

Comment: Is your server configured correctly to be able to send email with the correct email server etc.? Are there any firewall/security issues withs ending email?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Getting this `array(4) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Saurabh Sharma" ["email"]=> string(32) "blaw@blaw.com" ["phone"]=> string(14) "999999999" ["message"]=> string(26) "Hi, This is a test message" }`

Comment: @FrankPl Yeah, server is sending mails correctly. If i add a static mail address within reply-to then it works but not after passing variable in it.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Now do `var_dump($to);` in your `if($sentmail){` or under `$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);`

Comment: AAAAAAAA!!! Man wait i mistakenly used "=" instead of "==" in if statement.
That's assigning a NULL to the variables. 
Thanks a lot for your help guys :) you all rock :)

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I guess that will do it then.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma So that should have read as `if($name=="" || $email=="" || $phone=="" || $message=="")` then. I had just noticed that too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Exactly! :) now i can't stop my laugh on my stupid mistake :P

Comment: @SaurabhSharma Hey.. it happens. Glad it works, cheers! (*Peace*)

Comment: @SaurabhSharma I edited your question's title from your edit. Resolved/On Hold etc. are reserved for StackOverflow staff only. An answer must be given and accepted to close a question. Thought you need to know that.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma You can either add an answer with your solution, or I can make one as well and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was a little mistake with the above code. I mistakenly added `=` instead of `==` while comparison.

This line:

```
if($name=="" || $email="" || $phone="" || $message="")
```

Should read as:

```
if($name=="" || $email=="" || $phone=="" || $message=="")
```

Since `=` is for equation and not a condition for comparison `==`

Fixed it in the Question

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have php warnings and notices enabled. When you are echoing out $name, $email, etc you are doing a redirect using headers after that. If your php notices etc aren't turned on, your header redirect will fail due to having already echoed something, and you won't know that you had invalid input. This is part of the reason you shouldn't echo things out during logic, but should store and out put values later.

Comment: Yup @Zak I know it, i am just using it for testing :)